# Trained Tesseract still not accurate enough

Tags: java, tesseract

I'm training tesseract to be able to read the store in TFT. So what I am doing is training it with 24 pictures that look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8uQu.png). And with the help of jTessBoxEditor selecting the boxes like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfX6u.png), with the 5 champs of each picture and the 24 pictures. However, the result is not pretty accurate as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZYjT.png), when executing this code:

```
File ImageFile = new File("image.png");
ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
instance.setDatapath("D:\\jTessBoxEditor\\tesseract-ocr\\tessdata");
instance.setLanguage("TFTChamps");
String result = instance.doOCR(ImageFile);
System.out.println(result);
```

I have tried to add more pictures, but the result is the same. What should I do to improve the accuracy? Maybe increasing the quality of the images? However, as they are cropped screenshots, I don't know how I could improve their quality. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read and follow [docs](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/ImproveQuality.md):

[image]

```
tesseract improved.png -
Estimating resolution as 209
Aatrox a1 Kha'Zix ® 1 | Warwick ~/ 1 | Udyr #1 Vayne
```

With further image preprocessing (e.g. removing graphics element) you can more improve results.

Comment: Amazing, and you have done that without any custom language? Just by improving the quality of the image?

Comment: Exactly. Just image improving. Just remark: I use tessdata_best repository for language data.